# Redux devtools connection to localhost not working

Tags: redux, redux-devtools

I added `Redux` `DevTools` to my *Chrome* browser as started using `Redux`.
The `DevTools` have option in *Settings* to use no connection or use local server connection. I am working on localhost so I am trying to connect using local server. But it doesn't appear to do anything. Upon clicking *Connect* it just does nothing and the state is still undefined in the *Actions* tab.

I have put `localhost` as a hostname and my localhost app port as a port. It should be no brainer but is there anything I am doing wrong?

The result is I am unable to see the redux state despite it looks that everything is working, eg. I am getting the data and the react is debugging through the redux reducers correctly.

[image]

Comment: No one can help on this?